# How to call a JavaScript function from within Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I need to call a JavaScript function from Selenium WebDriver in Firefox. 
I use this command in Firebug's Command Editor to invoke a file upload application after logged into my website:

```
infoPanel.applicationManager.changeApp('FileUploader', {action: 'new'})
```

Is there a way to execute this from Selenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WebDriver driver = new AnyDriverYouWant();

if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor)

{

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("yourScript();");

}
```

Comment: When you run this after loading a page in webdriver, this javascript is added to the page and it remains there until I reload the page. Is there a  way to remove this javascript from the page after executing it only once?

Comment: I will need to check for that , will let you know solution when I get.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("yourScript();");
```